# How to get table name from another table in select query in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, data

In my sql in SFMC i am trying to get table name from another table in SELECT query but it seems to be not working, considering declaring variables in not allowed in SFMC SQL

**I have tried this but no luck**

```
SELECT * from (select de_name from ENT.DISTINCT_DE_TABLE) WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com'
```

**I have tried this as well, still no luck**

```
With TableVariable As (
   SELECT DE_NAME FROM ENT.DISTINCT_DE_TABLE
   )

SELECT * FROM from mytable where mytable = (SELECT DE_NAME FROM With TableVariable) WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com'
```

**Another approach - no luck**

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM
 (
    SELECT de_name 
    FROM ENT.DISTINCT_DE_TABLE
 ) AS x
WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com'
```

Any advise on how to go about it?

**NOTE:** email field does not exist in ENT.DISTINCT_DE_TABLE, it exists in the table that will be pulled from ENT.DISTINCT_DE_TABLE as DE_NAME.

**UPDATE - Adding table schemas here for more clarity on my question**

**- DISTINCT_DE_TABLE scheme (this table only holds the audience list names, nothing else):**

| **FieldName** | **Data Type** |
| --- | --- |
| DE_Name | text |

**- Records in DISTINCT_DE_TABLE look like this:**

| **DE_NAME** |
| --- |
| NewsletterEmail_audienceDE_Table |
| CouponEmail_audienceDE_Table |
| OrderEmail_audienceDE_Table |

**- Example of audience DE schema (picking any random DE):**

| **FieldName** | **Data Type** |
| --- | --- |
| email | emailaddress |
| c_id | int |
| name | text |

**- Sample data in audience DE**

| **email** | **c_id** | **name** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john@abc.com | 101 | John Lee |
| mike@yahoo.com | 102 | Mike H |
| Lee@gmail.com | 103 | Lee Jr |

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an alias if using a subquery. Below I have aliased as "x". It is also recommended to specify the column names instead of using shorthand "*".

```
SELECT x.[column01], x.[column02], x.[column03] 
FROM
 (
    SELECT [column01], [column02], [column03]
    FROM ENT.[DISTINCT_DE_TABLE]
 ) AS x
WHERE x.[column02] = 'abc'
```

although the above can simplified to this:

```
SELECT [column01], [column02], [column03]
FROM ENT.[DISTINCT_DE_TABLE]
WHERE [column02] = 'abc'
```

Comment: Hi charliefay thank you for the subquery, i missed one important aspect of my query in my question which i just updated, i have a where clause in the query in which the criteria used the field that exist in the table name that is being pulled (NOT in the table ENT.DISTINCT_DE_TABLE). any advise on that?

Comment: In your revised code you are using `email` column which is undefined since in the subquery you are only selecting a single field called `de_name`. So only this column is available in the outer query where clause.

Comment: Hi @charliefay my apologies if I wasn't clear in my question, I have added table schema and sample data of tables I am working with. The field in where clause DOES NOT exist in DISTINCT_DE_TABLE which is my issue. DISTINCT_DE_TABLE only holds the DE names. email field exist in the actual DE. Hope that helps in clarity.

Comment: Hi charliefay - I just wanted to follow up if you got a chance to review my response / update?

Comment: I think I understand now. You want to change the FROM table name based on a lookup to the DISTINCT_DE_TABLE. In this case, it is not valid SQL to use a subquery. You will need to use Server Side Javascript to construct the sql text dynamically.

Comment: Hi Charliefay - that is correct, I am currently exploring  SSJS approach. But yes, i was hoping if there is an easier way to do it in sql query.